# How to make simple android OCR working for multiple languages at same time..?

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

I am making an application in which user is support to select language as per there choice for detection i followed gautam gupta's OCR tutorial for implementing OCR in android. my problem is it supports only 1 language at a time but i want to add multiple languages insted of 1 language is i possible..?
here is the code which i got for OCR 
[https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR ] 
is there any solution please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the trained data files for both languages and initialize Tesseract with both language codes, for example:

`baseApi.init("/mypath/", "eng+hin");`

Speed and accuracy will be decreased. There's more info in the [javadoc](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/d0898ff9e73786770926857de58f8d6e93eb64ac/tess-two/src/com/googlecode/tesseract/android/TessBaseAPI.java#L251).

Comment: thanx a lott i fixed it up..:)

Comment: This is crashing for me with an error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data file not found at <path>/eng1+eng.traineddata. All the traineddata files are there and if I run with just eng1 or just eng it works.

Comment: @JohnSmith Good catch--this has been fixed.